# Between high and low : name

Tags: terminology

I have a list : 1, 3, 5, 7,10. 
1 is lowest and 10 is highest.

Is there a term to define the numbers in between (3,5,7)

All I can think about is inbetweeners

Comment: I don't think I've ever needed this, but intermediate values might be one wording. You might need to define or explain this in your presentation or paper. I don't think it's anybody's technical term.

Comment: I've removed the tag "median", which I can't see as germane.

Comment: intermediate sounds good.